# Dismiss a modal window from a completion block callback in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, closures, viewcontroller

My goal here is to determine through an url request if a modal window should be dismissed or not, but my code here doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
func dissmissIfServerTellsMeTo() {
        LoginRequest.checkTokenIsStillValid(completionHandler: { (response) in
            if let result = response.result {
                guard result else {
                    print("Access denied")
                    return
                }
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you check whether the part after `guard` is executed?

Comment: Yes I did and it does.

Comment: Can you check if completion is executed in `self.dismiss` ?

Comment: Try doing it from the main thread

Comment: Main thread fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI operations must be execute on main thread.
So, try to dismiss on main thread.

```
func dissmissIfServerTellsMeTo() {
LoginRequest.checkTokenIsStillValid(completionHandler: { (response) in
    if let result = response.result {
        guard result else {
            print("Access denied")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
})
}
```